# Блог на ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, create-react-app

Как сделать динамический вывод постов на `react` как на скриншоте? Чтобы при добавлении нового поста, старый изменялся в масштабе.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Не понят вопрос в плане "старый изменялся в масштабе". Можно конкретнее? Чтобы предыдущие картинки меняли масштаб и смещались?

Comment: Да, чтобы предыдущие картинки меняли маштаб и смещались

Comment: Ну, это все используется гридом, вроде как
https://html5book.ru/css-grid/

Comment: Вы немного не поняли, нужно сделать чтобы при добавлении нового поста, старый менял свой размер и расположение, а новый вставал на предыдущее место старого

Answer (score 1):

Товарищ @Huskey вам всё верно сказал, используйте грид и задавайте нужные размеры.

Сохраняете данные постов в state

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
```

Обновляете state при добавлении нового поста

```
const newPost = (newPost) => setPosts([...posts, newPost])
```

Рендерите всё это дело

```
return <div className='grid'>{posts.map((p, idx)=> <div className={idx===0 ? 'first' : 'notFirst'}>{p.name}</div> )}</div>
```

С css думаю сами разберётесь.